# document.querySelectorAll() changing behavior after finding a specific element

Tags: javascript, html, selectors-api

When I am on this fully loaded website and run a `document.querySelectorAll('input')`, I get 8 Nodes back. If I run it again, I will keep getting 8 back.

This is incorrect because there actually is a Node with `input#fileName` selector that is not getting picked up.

So I ran a `document.querySelectorAll('input#fileName')` and it picks up the Node.

Then I reran the same `document.querySelectorAll('input')` and now the output has changed to length of 5 nodes **including**  `input#fileName`.

I need this to pick up the 5 nodes **includnig** `input#fileName` from the beginning because Puppeteer headless browser framework is timing out when I try to get `input#fileName`.

Does anyone know why this maybe happening? Is html getting injected after DOM has been initialized and `document` isn't aware of the changes? Is there a different selector command I should try?

Thank you.

Attached a screenshot to show what's going on..

[image: The weird behavior]

Comment: May be the element is in another frame. Can you share the website name?

Comment: @VigneshRaja That's exactly what it was. Thank you! It's very confusing because if I am specific enough it grabs the child of the iframe... and starts grabbing only the children of iframe afterwards.